# How to convert decimal number to binary, octal and hexadecimal number in SPIM?

Tags: assembly, decimal, spim, number-systems, pcspim

```
.data
strIn:  .asciiz "\nEnter a number:"
reply:  .asciiz "\nYour input is:"
hexdigits:  .asciiz "0123456789abcdef"
hexword:    .asciiz "00000000"`
hexresult: .asciiz "\nHexadecimal code is:"`
buffer: .space 10

.text
.globl main
main:
#STEP 1 -- get the decimal number
#Print a prompt asking user for input
li $v0, 4                  
la $a0, strIn     
syscall                    

#Read in the number
la $a0, buffer
la $a1, buffer
li $v0, 8
syscall

#Ouput the decimal number
la $a0, reply
li $v0, 4
syscall

la $a0, buffer
li $v0,4
syscall 

move $t1, $v0
```

I first try to do the hex number, which I find a method from the Net...

```
    # get the value and put it in $t2
loop3o: lw  $t2, ($t1)

# initialize values for the inner loop
la  $t6, hexdigits  
la  $t7, hexword        
li  $t3, 15         # the mask value
sll $t3, $t3, 28
li  $t4, 28         # loop3i counter and shift amount

# mask off the correct 4 bits for a hex digit 
# and shift for bit positions 0-3
loop3i: 
and $t5, $t2, $t3
srl $t5, $t5, $t4

# get proper hex digit
add $t5, $t5, $t6
lb  $t8, ($t5)
sb  $t8, ($t7)

# process loop values and branch
srl $t3, $t3, 4
addi    $t7, $t7, 1
addi    $t4, $t4, -4
bgez    $t4, loop3i

# output the hex word   
li  $v0, 4
la  $a0, hexword
syscall

# process loop values and branch
addi    $t0, $t0, -1
addi    $t1, $t1, 4
    bgtz    $t0, loop3o



la  $a0, hexresult
li  $v0, 4
syscall
```

It doesn't work at all.How can I do it in SPIM?

> The ouput should be somthing like this...
>
> Enter a number: 23
>
> Input number is 23
>
> Binary code is 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0111
>
> Octal code is 000 0000 0027
>
> Hexadecimal code is 0000 0017

Comment: Is this an assignment? Does your professor have office hours? Have you come up with some ideas besides Googling?

Comment: btw, the value is inputted as string, ie. buffer contains '2', '3' after entering "23" by user? Then you need first to calculate the input value from buffer, before you can convert it to hex/bin/oct ... Check in debugger, what the memory and registers contains.

Comment: Thanks @Ped7g , I've just generate the correct ouput.

Comment: @MargaretBloom becoz im not that familiar with the coding in assbemly language...